# How would I get a bunch of questions to appear in random order in an inputbox one at a time?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, vba, input

I am creating a quiz in visual basic where I want a bunch of questions to appear in a new order, each time it is played and that are shown in input boxes one after the other and the user then puts their answer into the input box. I know I could use an array, but how would I go about this? If not, what other ways are there?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will ask one question random from the provided list in parameter, and return the answer in a string.

```
Function AskRandom(rQuestions As Range) As String

 Dim uQuestionsCount As Long
 Dim uQuestion As Long

 uQuestionsCount = rQuestions.Count

 uQuestion = CLng(Rnd() * uQuestionsCount) + 1

 AskRandom = InputBox(rQuestions(uQuestion), "Question")

End Function
```